# How to make this css crossbrowser?

Tags: css

I don't know, how to make this code crossbrowser:
(it works only in safari and chrome)

http://jsfiddle.net/MWYnP/

```
body {
    padding: 10px 9px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #C5CCD4 71%, #CBD2D8 71%, #CBD2D8 100%);
    -webkit-background-size: 7px 1px;   
}​
```

Comment: It's only working in Safari & Chrome because you're only targeting Safari & Chrome with `-webkit-` prefixes.  (Safari & Chrome are Webkit browsers.)  So use CSS properties that are not specific to only Webkit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
body {
padding: 10px 9px;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #C5CCD4 71%, #CBD2D8 71%, #CBD2D8 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #C5CCD4 71%, #CBD2D8 71%, #CBD2D8 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #C5CCD4 71%, #CBD2D8 71%, #CBD2D8 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 0, color-stop(0.71, #C5CCD4), color-stop(0.71, #CBD2D8), to(#CBD2D8));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #C5CCD4 71%, #CBD2D8 71%, #CBD2D8 100%);
background: linear-gradient(left, #C5CCD4 71%, #CBD2D8 71%, #CBD2D8 100%);
background-size: 7px 1px;
-moz-background-size: 7px 1px;
-o-background-size: 7px 1px;
-webkit-background-size: 7px 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this to generate your gradient: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/. Also, don't use gradients, it is not compatible with other than the latest versions of browsers, and not even all of them. Instead make the gradient a image and repeat it.

Comment: Probably due to some incompatibility as I stated earlier. You could debug it yourself, here is the reference provided by Opera: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css3-linear-gradients/

Comment: Alternatively, you could provide complete working code that specifically answers the OP's question.